# Unable to graph Natural Logarithmic function

Tags: plotting

I am attempting to graph a logarithmic function using the following code;

```
Plot[{Log[1/(2-e^(-2 x))^.5]},{x,-6,6}]
```

however, I am getting only axis with no displayed graph. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help!

I have also tried

```
f[x_]=Log[1/(2-e^(-2x))^.5]
Plot[{f[x]},{x,-6,6}]
```

The domain [-6,6] was a random selection with no particular significance.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The Euler constant is `E`, not `e`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the way you wrote the Euler constant. Most builtin functions and variables in Mathematica are capitalized, so it should be `E`, not `e`. When Mathematica sees the lower case `e` it just seems like an undefined variable and switches to symbolic computation, which doesn't return a number so there is nothing to plot, hence the empty graph. So writing

```
Plot[{Log[1/(2 - E^(-2 x))^.5]}, {x, -6, 6}]
```

should solve your problem